# Convert hexadecimal character vector to raw vector in R

Tags: r, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal character vector shown below into a raw vector,

```
"58" "0a" "00" "00" "00" "02" "00" "03" "02" "00" "00" "02" "03" "00" "00" "00" "03" "13" "00" "00"
```

I have tried it using this code,

```
as.raw(hexvec)
```

But, this gives me the following result,

```
3a 00 00 00 00 02 00 03 02 00
Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: out-of-range values treated as 0 in coercion to raw
```

What I want is the same vector in Raw type vector(as returned by serialize function). Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's way to late to awser but it might help somebody else.

```
hexchar_vector <- c("58", "0a", "00", "00", "00", "02", "00", "03", "02", "00", "00", "02", "03", "00", "00", "00", "03", "13", "00", "00")

integer_vector <- base::strtoi(hexchar_vector, base = 16L) # Convert strings to integers according to the given base using the C function strtol, or choose a suitable base following the C rules.

raw_vector <- base::as.raw(integer_vector) # Creates objects of type "raw" from integers.
```

This gives, with pipes and without the namespace referal :

```
library(magrittr)
hexchar_vector <- c("58", "0a", "00", "00", "00", "02", "00", "03", "02", "00", "00", "02", "03", "00", "00", "00", "03", "13", "00", "00")

raw_vector  <- hexchar_vector %>%
  strtoi(16L) %>%
  as.raw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply the function *[charToRaw](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/raw.html)* for each element in the vector? 

Try to use this code?

```
 sapply(hexvec,charToRaw)
```

Comment: [@dariodip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4908652/dariodip) that returns a wrong result!